# How can I ignore build failures in Jenkins that are due to version control connection issues

Tags: hudson, jenkins

We, unfortunately, have to use ClearCase and our server has become very unstable over the past week and we are getting build failures every time ClearTool fails to connect to the server.

The failures aren't staying in Jenkins but and email error gets sent out anyway.

Is there a way to ignore failures due to VCS issues?

Thanks,
E

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. Not being able to check out the repository is an error condition that I would use Jenkins to discover -- in my opinion, this is the best behaviour.

In your specific case, you might be able to work around the problem using the [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin). In particular, it allows you to send emails to only those people who have checked something in since the last build. I guess if the repository cannot be checked out, this applies to no-one and no emails are sent.